# How to modify data in a column from a sheet and have it automatically modify itself in the same column but a different sheet in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say I have 2 sheets with column A being a list of clients that needs to be identical in every sheet and the rest diferent. What formula do I need to use so that when I modify a name/client refference/ data in sheet 1 column A it will automatically get modified in the same column in sheet 2?

Answer (score 0):

In cell A1 of Sheet 2, you can type the formula `=Sheet1!A1`, then fill this down so that it references the clients in Sheet 1.  Sheet1 would just be the name of your first sheet.